# Project fails to build: "gcroot.h This document is opened by another project"

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, wrapper

I'm trying to build a C++ wrapper for a C# class using the following tutorial:
[pragmateek C++ wrapper for C# class](http://pragmateek.com/using-c-from-native-c-with-the-help-of-ccli-v2/)

When I run build, I get this error:

> Error  C1001   An internal error has occurred in the compiler. [project name] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\msclr\gcroot.h  110

When I click on the error it does the following:
VS opens gcroot.h to line 110

```
void swap( gcroot<T> & _right )
    { //VS shows error on this line
            using std::swap;
            swap( _handle, _right._handle );
    }
```

I get multiple popup prompts all reading:

> "This document is opened by another project"

---

I'm using VS2017, .net 4.5

Is there some trick to this I'm not seeing? Is there a better or more modern/canonical way to wrap a .net class for use in C++? My end-goal is to develop in C# and provide an API for the client in C++. My client got too far into the project to turn back, and then lost their C# guy and now wants me to switch my part of the project to C++.

I've spent a ton of time on google already.

Update:
Adding either of the following causes it to throw the error:

```
#include <vcclr.h>
#include <msclr\auto_gcroot.h>
```

Comment: I am gcroot. Sorry. I had to.

Comment: That is *also* true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and found a working solution for me:

**Solution:**
Change your wrapper build from ***.exe*** to **.dll**

VS:
Project `Properties->Configuration properties->General->Configuration Type->Dynamic Link Library (.dll)`

**Explained:**
i had the same issue and changed `Project Properties->Configuration properties->C/C++->All Options->Conformance mode` from `Yes (/permissive-)` to `No`

A new build indicated a linker entry-point error: `LNK1561` `entry point must be defined`

A quick check of the build configuration revealed the wrong `Configuration Type` (exe instead of dll)

Comment: Long version: I forgot to do this on my test project, and had my linking set up such that a dependent wrapper class was using the "release" version of the DLL, thus the changes had not fed forward due to me not building for release.